# What IBM_Q backend supports Qiskit Pulse?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I was doing an experiment with open pulse on caliberation of a qubit and I stumbled upon this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Input In [73] in <cell line: 1>
frequency_sweep_results = job.result(timeout=120) # timeout parameter set to 120 seconds
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/job/ibmqjob.py:290 in result
raise IBMQJobFailureError(
IBMQJobFailureError: 'Unable to retrieve result for job 627bcffafd267c3dbc4f42f7. Job has failed: The Qobj pulse type is not supported by the selected backend. Error code: 1108.'

Error code 1108 being :
Run the job on a backend that supports open pulse. Whether a backend supports open pulse can be found in its configuration data.

Use %tb to get the full traceback

I have used ibmq_santiago,ibmq_manila and ibmq_lima so far all giving me the same error.

Could someone suggest a backend that supports qiskit pulse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the backends with pulse support in the [table view of IBM service list](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems&view=table):

[image: backends with OpenPulse support]

Programmatically, you can list the backends with pulse support you have access to in the following way:

```py
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backends_supporting_openpulse = provider.backends(filters=lambda b: b.configuration().open_pulse)
```